# warbler WAR to deploy at tomcat, trouble with relative URL root

Tags: tomcat, jruby, warbler

I have a **Rails 4.2.7.1** project that I'm attempting to deploy to **Tomcat 7** with **JRuby 9.1.5.0** and **Warbler 2.0.4**
When I deploy it to the root context it works fine. If I deploy it to some other context (/myApp, for example - tomcat does it so), images under PUBLIC are not found because the path is incorrect.
The assets are searched for "/", but are under "/myApp/".
Can I specify the warbler (/config/warble.rb for example)?
Or how else can I set the path correctly?

Comment: this is with `assets:precompile` right, any customizations to config.assets?

Comment: @ha-sch could you able to figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying to sub-directories can be a pain.

First check if the asset_host is correct:

`config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://your.site/myApp'`

and `config.ru` looks like:

```
map '/myApp' do
  run ApplicationName::Application
end
```